# Build an ATI client using jss7 on Eclipse

Tags: java, restcomm, ss7

Hello Everybody I need to build a simple ATI client using **restComm jss7** library but I don't know where to start. How can I find out which packages and files I would require to import and how can I modify the ATI client if any is given in **jss7**

Comment: @jeand thanks for your response on my last question. Can you please answer it.

Answer (score 0):

"simple ATI client" is present in Restcomm SS7 Simulator (https://github.com/RestComm/jss7/tree/master/tools/simulator) - "Testing task" == "ATI_TEST_CLIENT".

Comment: That's not easy to read. For me it's not helpful. Please rewrite your answer.